# How to test an abstract factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, factory, abstract-factory

I'm trying to use an abstract factory in Python, minimally reproduced with the following 3 files:

## test_factory.py

```
from factory import Factory

def test_factory():
    factory = Factory.makeFactory()
    product = factory.makeProduct('Hi there')
    print(product)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_factory()
```

## factory.py

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from product import ConcreteProduct

class Factory(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def makeProduct(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def makeFactory(cls):
        return ConcreteFactory()

class ConcreteFactory(Factory):
    @classmethod
    def makeProduct(cls, message):
        return ConcreteProduct(message)
```

## product.py

```
class ConcreteProduct(object):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self._message = message
    def __str__(self):
        return self._message
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to mock this code to verify that `ConcreteProduct.__init__` is invoked with an appropriate value. Since the test file never sees `product.py`, I'm not sure how to accomplish this, or if it's even possible. I suspect that there is something more fundamentally wrong with my design here.

Comment: `Factory.makeFactory` should probably return `cls()`, not `ConcreteFactory()`, to avoid any dependency on a particular child class.

Comment: @chepner it would return a `Factory` instance in that case with the code as I have it. Is there a better way to structure this?

Comment: `cls` is bound to whatever class invokes the method, not the class that defines the method.

Comment: Right, I'm invoking it directly from `Factory`, so `cls` will be `Factory`.

Comment: If `ConcreteFactory` is the only child of `Factory`, then there isn't much point in having separate base and child classes; and if there is another child aside from `ConcreteFactory`, then why should `Factory.makeFactory` return an instance of one over the other? Typically, the factory function would be called with an argument to specify which class to use to create an instance; one way of doing that is to invoke `makeFactory` directly from the class you want to instantiate.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is `patch` `factory.ConcreteProduct` module reference.

So your test can be (not tested):

```
from factory import Factory
from unittest.mock import *

@patch("factory.ConcreteProduct")
def test_factory(mock_product_factory):
    mock_product = mock_product_factory.return_value
    factory = Factory.makeFactory()
    product = factory.makeProduct('Hi there')
    self.assertIs(product, mock_product)
    mock_product_factory.assert_called_with('Hi there')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_factory()
```

If (and only if) `ConcreteProduct` reference in `factory` module desn't exist in your test environment you can use `create=True` `patch`'s attribute to inject it.

I would like to point out that `ConcreteProduct` reference in `factory` module is already a *factory*. Class in Python are factories yet, this is not a typed language and the factory concept is less rigid than java. I'm coming from Java background and I still use factories even in python but they become real useful when you should manipulate the input to create a correct object, if your factory method is just an arguments pass through  to a class reference consider to remove the man in the middle.

Comment: This was very helpful. Please see my answer if you want to discuss further or have any suggestions.

Comment: @anderspitman I've changed my answer to clarify the miss understanding about `create` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

So far I've ended up with a solution that I was led to by @Michele dAmico's answer, and it is very close to his.

`test_factory.py` becomes:

```
from factory import Factory
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('product.ConcreteProduct.__init__', return_value=None)
def test_factory(mock_init):
    factory = Factory.makeFactory()
    product = factory.makeProduct('Hi there')
    mock_init.assert_called_with('Hi there')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_factory()
```

Note that I'm patching `product.`, not `factory.`, so I'm basically sidestepping `factory.py` and mocking what I know it's going to import. I don't know how I feel about breaking encapsulation this way, but honestly that's the way I feel about mocking in general.

I preferred this over the other answer because it's a little shorter, and because according to [the mock docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) it can be dangerous:

> By default patch will fail to replace attributes that don’t exist. If
>   you pass in create=True, and the attribute doesn’t exist, patch will
>   create the attribute for you when the patched function is called, and
>   delete it again afterwards. This is useful for writing tests against
>   attributes that your production code creates at runtime. It is off by
>   default because it can be dangerous. With it switched on you can write
>   passing tests against APIs that don’t actually exist!

I would certainly be interested in further discussion as I still have a sense that I can learn some better design methods to make this cleaner.

Comment: Take care that patch `__init__` can be dangerous if `ConcreteClass` derive from an other class and don't override it (python is not Java, constructor can be inherit). Moreover use to patch `__init__` just as last chance in the case that init do something that you don't want in your test like start a thread or open a remote connection, otherwise avoid it if you can: patch just public method is a good rule, avoid to patch private and magic method if you can. By this rule your test will be more simple and maintainable.